# UIButton not clickable when adding it programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uibutton

I'm creating custom `UIView` that contains two `UILabel`s and `UIButton` so I created a subclass to make this possible.

Now the process looks like:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.settingsButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width - 2 * margin, frame.size.height - titleHeight - dateHeight, buttonSize, buttonSize)];
    [self.settingsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self addSubview:self.settingsButton];

    [self.settingsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return self;
}
```

Button appears on UIView but it is not clickable. I tried to set `self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` and a couple things but still no result :(

Comment: Check with https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html if there isn't an view blocking the touch?

Comment: This looks okay. How does the rest look?

Comment: Make sure the button is not outside the UIView's bounds.
Easy test: set `clipsToBounds=YES` and see if the button is still visible

Comment: @Larme @Wasserfloh this test and debugger's test shows that button is inside `UIView`'s bounds so I have no idea now

Comment: In response to @Larme 's comment ,  Press View Hierarchy Debug button on your debug console and see if there is any other view on top of button

Comment: Does the parent view of the button have `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES`?

Comment: Can you give a link for demo , so we can check it in depth ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most dumb mistake I've ever made. Transparent `UINavigationBar` was blocking the touch.